# chef -- pass an attribute hash to a resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, chef-solo

chef has many resources\providers\definitions, for each of which there are attributes that can be set. for instance, [see](http://docs.opscode.com/resource.html) this and [this](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html).

by examine few definitions, it is cleat the the attributes given for a specific resource\provider\definition are packed into a hash pointed by the *param* variable.

i was wondering whether there is the ability to use a resource\provider\definition without unpacking a hash. here is a pseudo-code or my intentions:

```
attr = { :name => "/tmp/folder", :owner => "root", :group => "root", :mode => 0755, :action => :create }
directory attr
```

instead of writing it as follows:

```
directory "/tmp/folder" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode 0755
    action :create
end
```

is there a native way of achieving something alike?
thanks you, roth.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following

```
attrs = { .. }

directory "/tmp/folder" do
  attrs.each do |method_name, value|
    send(method_name, value)
  end
end
```

More about Ruby's send: [http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/**send**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/__send__)

Comment: thanks, that perfectly just solved a problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

> by examine few definitions, it is cleat the the attributes given for a specific resource\provider\definition are packed into a hash pointed by the param variable.

This is only true for [definitions](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html).

In the case of resources the common attributes (retries/actions/etc) are a mixture of attributes and methods in the [Chef::Resource](http://rdoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Resource) class (super class of all resources). For the resource specific attributes they are typically defined as methods on the resource in question. In the case of LWRPs Chef will generate a class behind the scenes and add each of the attributes as methods to that class.

> i was wondering whether there is the ability to use a resource\provider\definition without unpacking a hash.

The Chef::Resource class has a `json_create` method, so assuming you converted your hash to JSON it may be possible. More generally I'm curious as to the reason for wanting to do this as I believe that it will make your recipes harder to understand.